# What is a bromide?

Tags: meaning, etymology, books

I just finished reading Ayn Rand's wonderful *Fountainhead*, but one point that escaped me was Rand's near-constant use of the word **bromide** to refer to something disappointing, or a "bummer" in the vernacular.
When I searched online, I only found chemistry references....does anyone know what it means? Can anyone identify the etymology of this word?

Comment: **[bromide](http://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=bromide)**: 2 a. A commonplace remark or notion; a platitude. See Synonyms at cliché. b. A tiresome person; a bore. **[bromide](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bromide)** a. a drug that makes a person calm b: a statement that is intended to make people feel happier or calmer but that is not original or effective.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You didn't search very hard.  [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bromide_%28language%29) has a clear enough answer.

> A bromide is a phrase or platitude that, having been employed excessively, suggests insincerity or a lack of originality in the speaker.

(the literary reference derives from the chemical one, btw.)