# What's this about bromide?

Tags: expressions

What's this about bromide? It was suggested as a word representing stating the obvious. I'm not familiar with this expression. English is not my first language.

Comment: What was the context in which it was used? Have you checked a [dictionary definition](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bromide) or [two](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/bromide)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a bromide?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/168894/what-is-a-bromide)

Comment: "I'm not familiar with this expression." <-- Which expression do you mean? "Bromide" is a word, not really an expression. (I'm not nitpicking; I'm wondering whether you have an actual expression in mind.)

Answer (score 3):

[Potassium bromide](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Potassium_bromide) was widely used as a sedative in the 19th/early 20th century. Hence, the term *bromide* came to be used to mean, not so much 'stating the obvious' as 'a trite statement intended to reassure people and make them feel good'.